# Edge modal blocking login automation using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog, microsoft-edge

I am writing a python script that logs into edge using msedge-selenium-tools. When I run the script, a modal appears, and I can't seem to get any css selectors to use in Selenium. Here is my current code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions, Edge
from time import sleep
import requests
from pprint import pprint
import random
import os

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True

def wait_for(sec=2):
    sleep(sec)

driver = Edge(executable_path="./edgedriver_win64/msedgedriver.exe", options=options)

try:
    driver.get('https://login.live.com/')
    wait_for(5)
    email_input = driver.find_element_by_id("i0116")
    email_input.clear()
    email_input.send_keys(os.environ['email'])
    email_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    wait_for(10)
    password_input = driver.find_element_by_id("i0118")
    password_input.clear()
    password_input.send_keys(os.environ['pass'])
    password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    wait_for(3)
```

I attached an image of the modal I receive.[image: Edge Modal]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. When the webdriver launches the Edge browser and displays the modal, I tried right-click > inspect, or ctrl + shift + i to get into the front-end to inspect but could not perform these actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can avoid from this notification by adding `options.add_argument('inprivate')`

also according your code you import useless library ,
any way I edit your code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from time import sleep
import os


options = Options()
options.use_chromium = True
options.add_argument('inprivate')
def wait_for(sec=2):
    sleep(sec)

driver =webdriver.Edge( options=options)

try:
    driver.get('https://login.live.com/')
    wait_for(5)
    email_input = driver.find_element_by_id("i0116")
    email_input.clear()
    email_input.send_keys(os.environ['email'])
    email_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    wait_for(10)
    password_input = driver.find_element_by_id("i0118")
    password_input.clear()
    password_input.send_keys(os.environ['pass'])
    password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    wait_for(3)
```

Comment: This solution should work, but it only applies to Selenium 4. @Daikyu seems to be using Selenium 3 so msedge-selenium-tools is required to use `add_argument`.